# Heroku deployment issues when using Raspberry Pi 3B+ gpiozero

Tags: python, heroku, raspberry-pi, pi

I have successfully connected to my raspberry pi and can remotely control it using gpiozero. Documentation found here: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

I have connected to the pi using this: [gpiozero remote factory example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeiRS.png).

I have a webpage built using Flask that allows me to control pins of the Raspberry Pi thanks to the gpiozero library. Though I believe gpiozero is a source of error when deploying to Heroku. Atleast, that is how I can replicate the issue. When I deploy a simple webpage to Heroku, it works as intended. The moment I include gpiozero and include a connection to the Pi, there is an issue. These are the error logs produced by Heroku:
[Heroku error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohza5.png).
[Heroku error logs again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdEHP.png).
Is there a way around this issue?

Essentially, how can I deploy a flask webpage even with gpiozero?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: That's a private IP address. It isn't something that can be accessed from outside of your local network.

Comment: I can access it from outside that network though... @Chris

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by "that network", and networking is _way_ too big a topic to handle here and actually off-topic. But 192.168.1.3 is [a private address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses): "These addresses are not routed on the Internet". You _can_ route between them in a private network, but a machine on the Internet will _not_ be able to access them. Carefully consider the security implications, but you could configure a port forward or something from your public IP address, but that address might not be static.